# reconfiguring php? or do I have to reinstall?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, configuration

Alright, so I need the soap extension enabled in php. When I run phpinfo(), it's not there, so I'm guessing I have to recompile?

I can follow tutorials online to recompile the most recent php version for centos, but will it generally just work after that? Or does apache need to know to use the new installation?

Thanks for any direction you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably: `yum install php-soap`  would do the trick. Whenever the PHP manual says 'you have to recompile' your first instinct should be 'there must be a package for my distribution'.

Unless you already did compile PHP by hand, in which case it might be necessary to take the more difficult route.

Comment: Compiling PHP by hand is actually rather simple but more complicated then a package obviously.